# filling pandas dataframe columns based on another dataframe's columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this(df):

```
HOUSEID    PERSONID      WHY_TRP
20000017      1            1
20000017      1            1
20000017      1            1
20000017      2            1
20000017      2            3
20000231      1            11
20000231      1            11
20000231      2            11
20000521      1            11
20000521      2            11
20000521      2            3
```

Each row describes a trip made by a person. I have another dataframe of the same kind in which each row describes a person(df_p):

```
    HOUSEID   PERSONID   
    20000017      1      
    20000017      2     
    20000231      1    
    20000231      2    
    20000521      1    
    20000521      2
```

I want to make three new columns in the second dataframe to show the frequency of 1, 3 and 11 for each person. basically I already have a second dataframe (df_p) with other features so I shouldn't use groupby. for some reason the first and second dataframe don't have the same number of people. that's why I needed the strategy below. This is the code I tried but took hours to complete(1 million iterations):

```
df_p.insert(2, 'WHY_TRP_1', 0)
df_p.insert(3, 'WHY_TRP_2', 0)
df_p.insert(4, 'WHY_TRP_3', 0)

def trip_counter(i, r):
  if r[2] == 1:
    df_p.loc[(df_p['HOUSEID'] == r[0]) & (df_p['PERSONID'] == r[1]), ['WHY_TRP_1']] += 1 
  elif r[2] == 3:
    df_p.loc[(df_p['HOUSEID'] == r[0]) & (df_p['PERSONID'] ==  r[1]), ['WHY_TRP_3']] += 1 
  elif r[2] == 11:
    df_p.loc[(df_p['HOUSEID'] == r[0]) & (df_p['PERSONID'] ==  r[1]), ['WHY_TRP_11']] += 1


for i ,r in df.iterrows():
  trip_counter(i ,r)
```

output:

```
     HOUSEID   PERSONID   WHY_TRP_1     WHY_TRP_3      WHY_TRP_11
    20000017      1            3            0            0
    20000017      2            1            1            0
    20000231      1            0            0            2
    20000231      2            0            0            1
    20000521      1            0            0            1
    20000521      2            0            1            1
```

Is there a faster way to do this?

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `pd.get_dummies`, `.groupby().sum()` and pd.merge() to get it back into the original dataframe (EDIT: I added in `pd.merge` logic just now to fully answer your question after taking another look. Does this answer?)

```
df1 = pd.get_dummies(df, columns=['WHY_TRP']).groupby(['HOUSEID', 'PERSONID']).sum().reset_index()
df2 = pd.merge(df, df1, how='left', on=['HOUSEID', 'PERSONID'])
df2
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer! I need to add these three columns to an existing dataframe that the numbers of this output doesn't correspond to my person dataframe so I can't just add columns. is there a way that works like my slow solution?

Comment: It's not clear to me what you are asking. Perhaps, update your question.

Comment: @alibakhtiari I have updated my answer after taking another look. Please accept as solution or let me know if there is something I missed. I think my columns are in a different order, but besides that I think it solves.

Answer (score 0):

Code:

```
(df.groupby(['HOUSEID','PERSONID'])
  .WHY_TRP.value_counts()
  .unstack(fill_value=0)
  .add_prefix('WHY_TRP_')
  .reset_index()
)
```

Output:

```
WHY_TRP   HOUSEID  PERSONID  WHY_TRP_1  WHY_TRP_3  WHY_TRP_11
0        20000017         1          3          0           0
1        20000017         2          1          1           0
2        20000231         1          0          0           2
3        20000231         2          0          0           1
4        20000521         1          0          0           1
5        20000521         2          0          1           1
```